# JSON.stringify() <input> values as numbers?

Tags: javascript, json, numbers, stringify, html-input

I am using `JSON.stringify()` on html `<input>`s to send through a websocket like so:

```
JSON.stringify({
    numberValue: $('#numberValue').val()
})
```

but it encodes `$('#numberValue').val()` as a `String`.

How can it be encoded as a `Number`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Convert it to an integer first.

```
JSON.stringify({
    numberValue: parseInt($('#numberValue').val(), 10);
})
```

Answer (score 3):

You can parse the string:

```
JSON.stringify({
    numberValue: parseInt($('#numberValue').val(), 10);
})
```

> The parseInt() function parses a string and returns an integer.

More info: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp